# Populate Data to Listview but Arrayadapter not working

Tags: java, android, hashmap, android-arrayadapter, simpleadapter

I am trying to populate the data from my `arrayList` to listview. But for some reason I get the error `error: no suitable constructor found for ArrayAdapter(activity2.SendPostRequest,int,int,ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int,HashMap<String,String>[]) is not applicable`

```
                JSONArray json = new JSONArray(data);
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>  arrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                try {
                for(int i=0;i<json.length();i++){
                    JSONObject e =json.getJSONObject(i);

                    map.put("id", String.valueOf(i));
                    map.put("Name", "Vorname: " + e.getString("meta_value"));
                    map.put("orderid", "id: " + e.getString("post_id"));
                    arrayList.add(map);
                    return map.toString();
                }
                    ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, arrayList);

                list.setAdapter(adapter);
                }catch (JSONException e){
                    Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), "Some JSON error occurred" + e.getMessage());

                }
```

Cant find anywhere the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArrayAdapter(activity2.SendPostRequest,int,int,ArrayList>)

> Problem is you pass this as the first parameter for giving context to the adapter.

`constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int,HashMap<String,String>[])`

**`Solution`**

Instead of this pass `this`

`getContext() or getActivity()`

because this may point to different contexts depends on were you using.

Refer to this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) to get insights about `this`keyword

Comment: @Arul_Mani so which part do I need to change?

Comment: @Arul_Mani because I changed it to `ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>>(this.getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, arrayList);` but `.getActivity` is red

Comment: instead of "this" pass getActivity or getContext()

Comment: @Arul_Mani so how should this code look like(I'm sorry if I dont check it:))

Comment: @Arul_Mani so it should look like this or?: `ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>>(activity2.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, arrayList);`

Comment: Try with that if is not works, then create assign 

`context = this` inside your onCreate method and use the context in recycler